# First iteration of async loop gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to fetch my media files data to load to my application. I need to make multiple ajax calls in sequence.

Problem: I get error saying "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". I am mapping auto_video_jobs_array in my render method somewhere.

Below code shows how I do ajax async calls in sequence and set the state current_auto_video_jobs. At the end of last ajax call I can console print the value of state current_auto_video_jobs and can see that it has objects in it.

(For making it easier to understand I am showing the variable and state declarations also in my ques)

```
var auto_video_jobs_array = [];
var auto_video_jobs_urls = [];



state = {
        MediaFiles: [],
        fileURLS: [],
        current_auto_video_jobs: [[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}],[{job_type:"", eta:0}]],
        current_auto_video_jobs_urls: [],
        loader: true
    };



componentDidMount = () => {

        var that = this;

        this.init_get_media_files();

       refreshIntervalId = setInterval(this.get_process_status.bind(this), 60000);    //new

    }

init_get_media_files() {

        var that = this;
        var URL_array = [];

        auto_video_jobs_urls = [];


        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url":url,
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
            },
            success: function (response, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                response.results.map((item, i) => {
                    URL_array.push(item.url)

                    auto_video_jobs_urls.push(item.latest_process_status)//new
                })
            },
        }
        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {


            //alert("yo");
            that.setState({
                MediaFiles: response.results,
                fileURLS: URL_array,

                current_auto_video_jobs_urls: auto_video_jobs_urls
            })


           this.get_first_process_status();

        });
    }
```

This  is where I make ajax calls in sequence

```
 get_first_process_status() { //this is where problem comes

        console.log("inside get_process_status")
        // console.log("current jobs are" + auto_video_jobs_urls[1])
        console.log("jobs url array length is " + auto_video_jobs_urls.length)

        auto_video_jobs_array = [];

        //initialize index counter
        let i = 0;
        let that = this;
        that.setState({loader:true})
        function next() {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls[i],
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
                },
                success: function(response, textStatus, jQxhr){
                    ++i;
                    if(i >= that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls.length) {
                        // run function here as its the last item in array
                        console.log("i reached last value" + i + " " + response)

                        that.setState({current_auto_video_jobs: auto_video_jobs_array, loader:false})
                        console.log("current jobs are" + that.state.current_auto_video_jobs[0])

                    } else {
                        // do the next ajax call                       
                        auto_video_jobs_array.push(response)
                        next();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        //start the first one
        next();
    }
```

When I run  get_first_process_status second time after an interval of say 10 sec then the error goes and media files get visible. This means that the ajax  are carried out in right way. It's just that state current_auto_video_jobs is not getting mapped in first time somehow.

It should have worked in the first time also. I am not able to see any reason for error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" as at the end of last ajax call the state gets set.

This is my map function

```
{this.state.current_auto_video_jobs[i].map((item, i) => {
                                                                    let w;
                                                                    if (item.eta <= 1) {
                                                                        w = item.eta
                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                        w = 0;
                                                                    let s = {
                                                                        width: ((w) * 100) + "%",
                                                                    };
                                                                    return <a href="#" className="btn">
                                                                        <div className="prog-medbtn" style={s}></div>
                                                                        {item.job_type}</a>
                                                                }
                                                            )}
```

How do I solve this? I have tried everything.

Also: When I carry out ajax call with async: false, then error doesn't come.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not best practice, but I'll sometimes prevent the error by just doing:

```
(this.state.current_auto_video_jobs[i] || []).map
```

So that if the item doesn't exist yet, instead of trying to call `map` on `undefined`, it instead calls it on an empty array.

Comment: No but the array exists. I can see getting printed in console. I just tried the method  you suggested. I still get the error

Comment: when `current_auto_video_jobs` is an empty array, `current_auto_video_jobs[i]` is undefined.

Comment: Yes I know. But it cannot be empty array at any point of time  as while initializing it also I have some put some elements in it. You cans the starting part of my code where I defined states.

Comment: It always will be an empty array at some point, you do: `auto_video_jobs_array = [];` and then you do: `that.setState({current_auto_video_jobs: auto_video_jobs_array, loader:false})`

Comment: But the thing works when I do async:false. What is the way out of this? What you suggested also didn;t work.

Comment: Are you maybe getting a different error or that same error somewhere else?  I really don't see how you would be getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` from the line of code that I gave you.

Comment: Got it solved. Just intialized  auto_video_jobs_array just like current_auto_video_jobs